# Can't list users - "select * from user" returns only one row with one column

Tags: postgresql

I have a heroku postgres add-on database with a user table. However, when I attempt to `select * from user`, all I get is:

```
  current_user  
----------------
 rtsjlhdfptlaqd
(1 row)
```

The table name is definitely `user`. There is no `users` table. There are definitely a bunch of users in my app, but I can't seem to list them.

Thoughts?

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010634/postgres-what-is-the-query-select-from-user-actually-doing but I can't seem to flag it as such because it's not a db exchange question. It's my own question - should I just delete it?

Answer (score 10):

Ok this is kind of a stupid question, but I'll leave it in case someone else makes a similarly dumb mistake.

For the record, I'm not the one who created a set of models including `user` instead of `users`.

Postgres has its own table `user` which it holds postgres users in. When you `select * from user` what you're getting is the result of the postgres `user` table. What you have to do instead is `select * from "user"` where user is in double quotes.

Comment: This is not really correct, see the output of `\dt *."user"`.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
select * from <schema-name>."user";
```

For example:

```
select * from public."user";
```

Note (my Postgres version):

```
# select version();
                                                         version                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 10.5 (Debian 10.5-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is that in this context, `user` is treated as a function (without parentheses!) and is synonymous to the `current_user` function. So it will always return a single result when used in the `FROM` clause, and that result is your current user name.